# Facebook App with dynamic domains

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, jquery-plugins

I am working on a plugin, and I use one Facebook App. The problem is, this plugin can be used for many users in the world, and many domains.
That domains is dynamic, I never know what is all of domain using my plugin. Is possible, in code, I specify the domains?

Im using javascript :)

Comment: what plugin you wan't to use?

Comment: What does your plugin do and how does the domain interact with it?

Comment: This plugin show the albuns of Facebook.